# Why am I unable to load files in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

I have just started learning clojure, but have a hard time understanding why my file structure is erroneous. In the main file(main.clj),
I have just this:

```
(ns example.core
    (:gen-class)
    (:load "declare"))

...some code...
```

and in 'declare.clj', which is in the exact same classpath "project/src", I have this:

```
(in-ns 'example.core)
...some code...'
```

From what I understand I should be hitting the right syntax, but I only receive

> Could not locate
>   clojurepractice2/src/clojurepractice2/declarations__init.class or
>   clojurepractice2/src/clojurepractice2/declarations.clj on classpath.

from REPL. I am using lein to code, which I know is supposed to automatically set the classpath. Is there something I am missing?
I have tried using `load-file` With the same results.

Comment: From reading the documents, albeit the tutorials are cursory from what I've seen.

Comment: You need to follow a tutorial or two before trying to piece it together on your own. AFAICT from the pretty minimal stuff you posted there's no point in using `:gen-class`. You should be using `:require` in your namespace declaration. It's not real clear what is in your source file and what you're typing in at the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

The `main.clj` should have namespace `example.main`. Or rename it to `core.clj`. This is definitely an issue with file name and namespace mismatch.

Comment: Actually, I am having an issue where I did make the change, but the error persists. Do you have any other idea of what could be causing it? Just for context, this is a fresh install on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

**Because the file name should be same as the namespace name.**
If your file is in **`src/example/main.clj`** then the namespace should be **`example.main`**.
The usage is

```
(ns example.main
    (:gen-class)
    (:load "declare"))
```

Is the file path as **src/example/main.clj** ? Is the `main` inside the `example folder` in `src`?